# Why is the culture kept after ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have the following async code:

```
// Main system culture is English here
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");

WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}:Culture:{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");

await Task.Delay(1).ConfigureAwait(false);

WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}:Culture:{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
```

The resul I expected would be to have a different thread id after the await and that new thread id having the unmodified system culture again.

This is not happening; the thread is indeed different from the previous, but the culture is somehow flowing from the previous thread.

Why is it keeping the culture if I **suggested** with `ConfigureAwait` that I don't need to keep the `SynchronisationContext`? It is my understanding that the culture is not stored on the `ExecutionContext` therefore I am not sure why this is happening.

This is a Console application.

Full example code: https://pastebin.com/raw/rE6vZ9Jm

Comment: You may already know this, but I'll bring it up just in case: since you're building a Console app, there is no `SynchronizationContext`, so `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't really change the behaviour of your code as posted - at least not in the way you'd expect.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy Thank you for the comment; I knew it already but I added it as I did not specify it was a console app initially (edited later).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is expected behaviour as of .NET 4.6.

The reason Julien could not reproduce it is that he's likely targeting a lower version of the framework (in 4.5.2, for instance, culture doesn't flow).

[Here is the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=netframework-4.7#Async) on the subject.

Specifically note the following:

> ... starting with apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6, asynchronous operations by default inherit the values of the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture properties of the thread from which they are launched. If the current culture or current UI culture differs from the system culture, the current culture crosses thread boundaries and becomes the current culture of the thread pool thread that is executing an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I was indeed using 4.6 and changing to 4.5 did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

A quick test on a new VS2017 Console project shows this output (en-GB is my default culture):

```
1:Culture:es
4:Culture:en-GB
```

Which is what you (and I) expected. Maybe something else is setting the culture independently?

Comment: It is a plain new Console application with not much else in it apart from the Main method and the Program class; this is why is so confusing. I will share the full source.

Comment: Tried setting the target framework to 4.6 and indeed, the output becomes

    1:Culture:es
    4:Culture:es